# Rename folder in Windows 7 created in Linux with '?' character

Tags: linux, windows, rename, characters

I have a folder in a external hard disk created from linux.
When I try to open that directory from Windows, I can't do it.
The name of the folder is **2013-?** with a special character who in Windows we can't open.
How to rename this folder from Windows 7 to open it? It exists a command line in DOS?

Comment: You can have fun trolling a wannabe Windows sysadmin by creating files that end in a dot eg: `echo Trolololol > \\?\C:\cant-touch-this.`  Only someone who knows the quirks and hacks of the Windows path parser can delete it :D  Even scandisk/chkdsk won't report any errors.

Comment: And before my previous comment creates a "how do I delete this" SO question, `del \\?\C:\cant-touch-this.` is the solution.  The ` \\?\ ` namespace prefix disables path parsing, which preserves the trailing dot.  This /might/ work for your `?` character problem too, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Answer (score 0):

- Option A: Run Scandisk Explorer -> Properties -> Tools -> Error-checking - this should / could fix it.
- Option B: Download TotalCommander and use this to rename the files